# Facebook Desktop Auth pop up Browser

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, desktop

I'm writing a desktop app in C# that has Facebook integration and I'm trying to figure out how to do authentication/login.  I have thought of two different approaches:

**1. Popup *default* browser**

- The user probably is logged into Facebook on their default browser.
- Code: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com/...");`
- **Issues/Questions: How do I control the window location and size (e.g. not show address bar when it starts)? Can I destroy the process after login is complete or even close the window (won't most browsers prompt for window closing if done from javascript?)?**

**2. Popup *specific* browser**

- If I lookup the default browser, I can pass command-line flags to the browser. `"..\chrome.exe" --app=http://www.facebook.com/...`
- **Questions**: How do I set the window size/location? How do I close the process after login-complete (assuming I know when the login is complete)?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

very usefull resource in this situation is http://facebooksdk.net/. 
Earlier, there was a sample project for desktop application on facebooksdk.net, but it was removed. You can see it here https://github.com/MarkAureliy/facebook-winforms-sample-master
This project is straight for your needs